# jQuery on hover out still retains its hover styles

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jquery script which is supposed to show a content box when hovered over the button.. and the button class hovered is also turned on. When the mouse is hovered inside the button div that was just triggered to show up, the button should still retain its hover styles. But whenever the mouse is hovered off the .hovered class should also be removed. Currently, when you hover over the button, and hover off without hovering over the child elements, the .hovered class is still retained. This needs to be removed.

The HTML code is as follows:

```
           <li><a href="#" class="login-btn">Login</a>
                    <div class="login-content">
                        <form name="login-form" action="" method="post">
                            <input type="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="E-mail" />
                            <input type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Password" />
                            <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" class="form-login" />
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </li>
```

The jQuery code is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$(".login-btn").hover(
   function() {
        clearTimeout($(this).data('hoverTimeoutId'));
        $(".login-content").show();
        $(this).addClass('hovered');
    },
    function() {
        clearTimeout($(this).data('hoverTimeoutId'));
        $(this).data('hoverTimeoutId', setTimeout(function () {

            $(this).removeClass('hovered');
            $(".login-content").hide();
        } ,500));
    });


$('.login-content').hover(
    function(){     
        clearTimeout($(".login-btn").data('hoverTimeoutId'));
    },     
    function(){    
        $(".login-content").hide();
        $(".login-btn").removeClass('hovered');
    });

});
```

Comment: What i find really strange is that I put your code into a JSFiddle, and it worked perfectly... http://jsfiddle.net/samhuckaby/VdVHx/

Comment: try adding a background color to the login btn.. and then hover the mouse over it so it gains a hovered class.. and the color would change to the specified style. Now, if you hover off without hovering over the inside elements, the color would not go away, meaning it still retains its style unless you hover over the child element and then off.

Comment: Grinn got it spot on.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Well, since this has been solved, I've updated my JSFiddle to reflect the correct code from below for any future searchers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The initial issue was that the context of `this` within a `setTimeout` function is not the element hovered. Instead, persist the context by first assigning it to a variable.:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".login-btn").hover(
   function() {
        clearTimeout($(this).data('hoverTimeoutId'));
        $(".login-content").show();
        $(this).addClass('hovered');
    },
    function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        clearTimeout($this.data('hoverTimeoutId'));
        $this.data('hoverTimeoutId', setTimeout(function () {
            $this.removeClass('hovered');
            $(".login-content").hide();
        } ,500));
    });


$('.login-content').hover(
    function(){     
        clearTimeout($(".login-btn").data('hoverTimeoutId'));
    },     
    function(){    
        $(".login-content").hide();
        $(".login-btn").removeClass('hovered');
    });

});
```

Comment: wow.. this works.. thanks soo much. Even though you mistakenly had"$loginBtn.hover" instead of "$(".login-btn").hover". Thanks Again.

Comment: Ok, good. I fixed that. So you're not having the issue of it still hiding with my code that you had with @SetSailMedia's? Honestly, I don't see the difference :)

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you're losing `$(this)` scope inside the `setTimeout` function. Can you try this simple replacement and see if it has any effect?

```
$(".login-btn").hover(
   function() {
        clearTimeout($(this).data('hoverTimeoutId'));
        $(".login-content").show();
        $(this).addClass('hovered');
    },
    function() {
        clearTimeout($(this).data('hoverTimeoutId'));
        $(this).data('hoverTimeoutId', setTimeout(function () {

            $(".hovered").removeClass('hovered'); // change here
            $(".login-content").hide();
        } ,500));
    });
```

If you have multiple `.login-btn` on the page, this may not be the most elegant solution because it can cannibalize the other element's hover. If that's the case, you might try:

```
var $btn = 0;
$(".login-btn").hover(
   function() {
        clearTimeout($(this).data('hoverTimeoutId'));
        $(".login-content").show();
        $(this).addClass('hovered');
    },
    function() {
        clearTimeout($(this).data('hoverTimeoutId'));
        $btn = $(this);
        $(this).data('hoverTimeoutId', setTimeout(function () {

            $btn.removeClass('hovered'); // change here
            $(".login-content").hide();
        } ,500));
    });
```

Comment: this creates another issue, that the as soon as the mouse is hovered off from the login btn.. the login content hides automatically after a second, and hovering over it is no use.

Comment: They are two different elements, `.login-content` and `.login-btn`, so I don't think I fully understand what the new problem is?

Comment: The login-content is inside the .login-btn. When the mouse is hovered over login-btn, login-content shows up, and the login-btn gains .hovered class. When the mouse is hovered off from login-btn, the login-btn loses its .hovered class. Similarly, when the mouse is hovered over the .login-content, the ".login-btn" should gain the .hovered class. And when the mouse is hovered off, it should lose its .hovered class. Hope you get it :)

Comment: OK I see what you are after, but in your HTML `.login-content` is not a child of `.login-btn`, they are both children of the `<li>` element.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `.hover()` which always triggers a mouseout event, you might want to give `.mouseenter.()` a try.

In one event you can clear active states and apply it to the current one.

```
var initVideos = function () {
    var divs = $("ul li a");

    // bind your hover event to the divs
    divs.mouseenter(function () {
        flashembed("videoArea", $(this).prop("href"));
        divs.removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
};

// once all is loaded
$(window).load(function () {
    initVideos();
});
```

**demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/tive/Ff7Mq/

**Approach 2:**

```
var btn = $(".login-btn"),
    content = $(".login-content"),
    triggers = btn.add(content);

triggers.mouseenter(function() {
    content.show();
    triggers.addClass('hovered');
});

content.mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).hide(500);
    btn.removeClass('hovered');
});
```

**demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/tive/GkVN3/

Comment: but I need a mouseout when the mouse hovers off from the login-btn, unless its hovering the login-content which is the popup div inside the login-btn.